# Cant access/change BIOS

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I have a Mecer ET15-T. I cannot change setting in the BIOS.

I endeavored to change the HDD for an SSD. Sadly the machine only has one USB port. Installing windows from a flash drive and having a keyboard is not possible because USB extenders do not work.

The BIOS can be accessed if I have the original HDD with Win8 by removing cmos battery. However, the keyboard cannot be used in BIOS, only in Windows.

It is necessary for me to enable the use of the USB keyboard to change setting in the BIOS. There is no PS2 port.

What options do I have available to me? Have I bricked the BIOS? There must be a way I can change BIOS settings within Windows.

I get "wmic bios invalid namespace" in cmd.
msinfo32 has error "cannot collect information".

Useful Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to change in BIOS? For USB I would recommend to use an active USB hub (own power supply) then multiple USB devices should work.

Comment: I want to switch on USB, and once that happens I can switch booting options. I will try a powered USB hub as soon as I can get the keyboard to work in the BIOS